# Чем накрыт этот скрипт и можно ли его деобфусцировать?

Tags: php, base64, reverse-engineering

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть скрипт который накрыт каким-то протектором, скрипт входа на сайт. Есть опасения, что там может быть вредоносный код.

*Хотелось-бы узнать, что это за энкодер?*

Провозился с ним всю ночь, ничто его не берёт из паблика. Буду очень благодарен за декодер или хотя-бы расшифрованный скрипт.

*Реально ли его деобфусцировать?*

**Сэмплы:**

> Зашифрованный файл: https://pastebin.com/etEWDu2S `eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('`
>
> The decrypted file (but the lines are obfuscated): https://pastebin.com/AWr6zGg1 `$GLOBALS['_1867101966_'][round(0)]`
>
> Другой файл route.php, тут вообще несколько блоков: https://pastebin.com/FmbSyYLZ `multiple eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('`

Всем удачи.

Comment: "или хотя-бы расшифрованный скрипт" Так что вам мешает? Тут 2 пути - либо сидеть и ручками прогонять все эти адские round через интерпретатор с целью получить, чему оно все-таки равно, либо раскопать какие-то библиотеки для парсинга синтаксиса PHP и написать автоматический парсер. По вкусу.

Comment: Но ведь это явно не руками шифровалось, это какой-то энкодер, если выяснить - какой, можно поискать декодер :)

Comment: Исходники вы навряд-ли получите, декодер навряд-ли есть. Всякие `round` логику не нарушает, можно бегло просмотреть файл и сказать - есть ли там уязвимости или нет.

Comment: посредством r2: www.rada.re

Answer (score 0):

Про автоматические средства не знаю (разве что своё написать под конкретно этот случай), но и руками скрипт вполне себе просто и быстро приводится в порядок. Ничего опасного в нём не наблюдается.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: ../');
    exit();
}

$message = '';

if (isset($_GET['data']) && isset($_GET['a'])) {
    $id = check($_GET['a'], "int");
    $STH = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`, `login`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id LIMIT 1");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $STH->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    if (empty($row->id)) {
        show_error_page();
    }

    if ($_GET['data'] != md5($row->id . $conf->code . $row->email . date("Y-m-d"))) {
        $message = '<p class=\'text-danger\'>' . $messages['Link_not_active'] . '</p>';
    } else {
        $password = crate_pass(7, 1);
        $password2 = convert_password($password, $conf->salt);
        $STH = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password`=:password WHERE `id`=:id LIMIT 1");
        if ($STH->execute(array(':password' => $password2, ':id' => $id)) == '1') {
            include_once "inc/notifications.php";
            $letter = recovery_letter($conf->name, $row->login, $password);
            sendmail($row->email, $letter['subject'], $letter['message'], $pdo);
            $message = '<p class=\'text-success\'>' . $messages['Recovery_pass1'] . $row->email . $messages['Recovery_pass2'] . '</p>';
            write_log("User reinstated pass #" . $row->email);
        } else {
            $message = '<p class=\'text-danger\'>' . $messages['Error_page'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

$tpl->load_template('elements/title.tpl');
$tpl->set("{title}", $page->title);
$tpl->set("{name}", $conf->name);
$tpl->compile('title');
$tpl->clear();

$tpl->load_template('head.tpl');
$tpl->set("{title}", $tpl->result['title']);
$tpl->set("{site_name}", $conf->name);
$tpl->set("{image}", $page->image);
$tpl->set("{robots}", $page->robots);
$tpl->set("{type}", $page->kind);
$tpl->set("{description}", $page->description);
$tpl->set("{keywords}", $page->keywords);
$tpl->set("{url}", $page->full_url);
$tpl->set("{other}", '');
$tpl->set("{token}", $token);
$tpl->set("{cache}", $conf->cache);
$tpl->set("{template}", $conf->template);
$tpl->set("{site_host}", $site_host);
$tpl->compile('content');
$tpl->clear();

$menu = $tpl->get_menu($pdo);

$nav = array(
    $PI->to_nav('main', 0, 0),
    $PI->to_nav('recovery', 1, 0)
);
$nav = $tpl->get_nav($nav, 'elements/nav_li.tpl');

include_once "inc/not_authorized.php";

$tpl->load_template('/index/recovery.tpl');
$tpl->set("{site_host}", $site_host);
$tpl->set("{template}", $conf->template);
$tpl->set("{message}", $message);
$tpl->compile('content');
$tpl->clear();
```